# Python3 Converting str with screened byte characters to str

Tags: python, python-3.x

How to convert this field from database

[image]

to

[image]

or to

[image]

Comment: `var1` is not valid to begin with, please update your question with valid input data. You need to escape all double-quotes within the string (which itself has double-quotes as outer characters, non-escaped)

Comment: None of the lines you show is valid, as you have internal double quotes. Do you actually have a dictionary, or some weird string representation of one (or a string representation of a string representation of a dict)? Do you want to get a dictionary out, or a string?

Comment: Added a picture of how it looks in the debugger. This line is taken from the database

Comment: You have updated the question, but still `var1` `var2` and `var3` are not valid in python. Your picture is not complete as it is excluding the end of that string.

Comment: Updated with images from debugger

Comment: Maybe what you are looking for is the codecs library. But all 3 lines of `var1`, `var2`, `var3` are all invalid. For actual help, you should correct them.

Comment: Added screenshots of how the variables look in the debugger.
response1 - from the database.
response2 is answer is from urllib.request.urlopen(url).read().
response5 is urllib.request.urlopen(url).read().decode("utf8")

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[EDIT]The question was updated and the below was answered based on the original question.

---

if you fix your input `var1` then you can do something like this:

```
var1 = '{"text":"tool","pos":"\\xd1\\x81\\xd1\\x83\\xd1\\x89\\xd0\\xb5\\xd1\\x81\\xd1\\x82\\xd0\\xb2\\xd0\\xb8\\xd1\\x82\\xd0\\xb5\\xd0\\xbb\\xd1\\x8c\\xd0\\xbd\\xd0\\xbe\\xd0\\xb5"}'
md = {}
for e in var1[1:-1].split(','):
    md[e.split(':')[0][1:-1]] = e.split(':')[1][1:-1]
md['pos'] = (bytes.fromhex(''.join([h for h in md['pos'].split('\\x')]))).decode('utf-8')
print(md)
```

output:

```
{'text': 'tool', 'pos': 'существительное'}
```

Comment: this solution is good only if the wrong characters only in "pos". A more universal solution is needed

Comment: I appreciate your comment; but please return the favor: update the question with your code; and I will certainly comment on that.